# Mysqldump through netcat in 3 server constellation

Tags: shell, mysql, netcat

I have the following scenario:

- Server A: Mysql Database server, only connection through mysql (port 3306), no shell access, no root
- Server B: www frontend server (nginx), no mysql / mysqldump; can connect to Server A, has shell access, no root
- Server C: root server with shell access, mysql, mysqldump

Is there a way to use mysqldump on Server C to dump databases from Server A?

Answer (score 1):

You can just tunnel mysql port to server C using ssh login to server B, something like that:

```
server_c$ ssh -L7777:server_a:3306 server_b
# keep that connection hanging for the sake of tunnel
server_c$ mysqldump --host=127.0.0.1 --port=7777
```

This way you'll end up connecting to server_a:3306, running client at server C, tunneling through server B. "7777" is just some random free port.

Answer (score 0):

NGINX Plus r5 has TCP load balancing features that you could use or you can use https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module for older versions. On Server B you'd do something like:

```
stream {

    upstream backend {
        server a.example.com:3306;
    }

    server {
        listen 3306;
        proxy_pass backend;
    }
}
```

and that would allow you to use `mysql` on Server C towards `b.example.com:3306` that would proxy you to Server A.

Comment: Hi Hans,Thanks for your solution. I got no access to NGinx config files.